# How can I create *.inc library files from source compile in OpenSSL source?

Tags: build, compilation, openssl

I need *.inc files of OpenSSL to encrypt string in MASM32 program.
I can create libeay32.dll, libeay32.lib in out32dll folder after compile Openssl source, but I can't create libeay32.inc file.
How can I make this library file?

And I created the out32dll folder using this command.

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=C:\aes\openssl-1.0.2n-install
ms\do_nasm
nmake ­-f ms\ntdll.mak
```

I have downloaded the ntdll.mak file from this.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B2GIWJjdyOXR6ycCLq8OpV4Skhg2N8ob/view
```